Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array LeetCode problem
Given an integer array nums sorted in non-decreasing order, remove the duplicates in-place such that each unique element appears only once. The relative order of the elements should be kept the same. Then return the number of unique elements in nums.
Consider the number of unique elements of nums to be k, to get accepted, you need to do the following things:

Change the array nums such that the first k elements of nums contain the unique elements in the order they were present in nums initially. The remaining elements of nums are not important as well as the size of nums.
Return k.

In this question this the code of mine trying to submit but
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        nums = set(nums)
        return len(nums)

why this line of code is not getting submitted.
Solution in python and explanation why this line of code doesnt working.

not getting submitted skipped hitting the button? not getting accepted? Mind in-place.

Your code is faulty because casting the list to a set doesn’t guarantee preserving the original sorted order and is not "in-place". While sets remove duplicates, they don’t maintain the insertion order of elements, which is required here (otherwise, you would need to sort again afterwards, which is obviously inefficient).
A more efficient approach is to use two-pointers since the array is already sorted. You can iterate through the list, and whenever you find a unique element, just move it to the front:
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: list[int]) -> int:
        if not nums:
            return 0
        k = 1
        for i in range(1, len(nums)):
            if nums[i] != nums[i - 1]:
                nums[k] = nums[i]
                k += 1           
        return k

This keeps the original order running in O(n) time with O(1) space since it modifies the array in-place.

Oops, you should first understand what it the difference between changing a mutable object in place, and replacing a variable with a new object.
Here:
a = [1, 2, 3]
a[1] = 4

I have changed the mutable list referenced by the a variable
But there:
a = [1, 2, 3]
a = [1, 4, 3]

a points to a new list object, totally unrelated with the original one.
Let's go one step further:
def alter_good(lst, val):
    lst.append(val)

def alter_wrong(lst, val):
    lst = lst + [val]

Here, alter_good will correctly alter the passed list, and the caller will be able to see the change. But alter_wrong will create a new list, only referenced by the local lst variable. On return that now object will be destroyed, and the caller will see no change in its list.
Said differently, while your code contains nums[i]=smthing you respect the contract; but as soon at it contains nums=..., you are wrong.

The main issue is that you do not modify the list in-place. The intended solution is to take advantage of the input being sorted, which means that all equal elements are adjacent. This allows you to simply take the first occurrence of each distinct value (when the current value is not the same as the value at the previous index).
For a simple way to fix your code, you can assign to a slice of the whole list, i.e. nums[:], which changes its actual content. However, set does not preserve insertion order, so this would not be fully correct. Instead, you can create a dict, which preserves the insertion order of its keys.
This produces a very concise solution:
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: list[int]) -> int:
        nums[:] = dict.fromkeys(nums)
        return len(nums)

